# How to add 4 hours to time in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm working on a blog migration from a custom built blog to Wordpress. One of the fields that Wordpress is looking for in the database is a date/time stamp set to GMT, which is 4 hours ahead of our time. So I basically need to take our date/time stamp (in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format), and add four hours to it. I was looking at the MySQL command "ADDTIME", but I think that only works on selects, not on inserts.

I had worked up a script that exploded the date in to parts, and added 4 hours to the time, but the ensuing logic that would be required to check for when 4 hours pushes in to the next day/month/year seemed a little excessive.

Comment: There's nothing that prevents you from doing it in the database. You could migrate the data over from the existing database without altering the timestamps then do UPDATE blog_table
SET blog_timestamp = DATE_ADD(blog_timestamp, INTERVAL 4 HOURS); -- which would accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
date($format, strtotime("$date + 4 hours"));
```

Answer (score 13):

There's nothing that prevents [`ADDTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) from being used in an `INSERT` OR `UPDATE`, but [`DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) is probably what will work best:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
SET my_datetime = DATE_ADD('2009-11-01 19:30:00', INTERVAL 4 HOURS),
...other insert columns here... ;
```

Comment: `UPDATE table SET field = DATE_ADD(field, INTERVAL 4 HOURS);` is a bit more generic :)

Comment: I presumed SerpicoLugNut had already extracted timestamps so that was the syntax I used. Each extracted timestamp would end up looking that way on INSERT. Funny, I added the generic format as a comment above right when you left yours. :-)

Comment: Thats `INTERVAL 4 HOUR` and not `INTERVAL 4 HOURS` on MySQL 5.5.44

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( "2009-08-09 23:44:22" )+4*60*60 )
```

or even

```
date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( "2009-08-09 23:44:22 + 4 hours" ) )
```

Might need a bit of error checking, but should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Or better in SQL

```
DATE(DATE_ADD(`Table`.`Column`, INTERVAL 4 HOURS))
```

Answer (score 2):

For all the answers using DATE_ADD, the correct syntax is "4 HOUR" not "4 HOURS" (at least in the current version of MySQL):

`UPDATE table SET field = DATE_ADD(field, INTERVAL 4 HOUR);`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the TZ of your database is set to GMT (UTC), which is as it should be.
You need to convert your local date into GMT when adding to the database.

from the MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual:

```
CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)
```

CONVERT_TZ() converts a datetime value dt from time zone given by from_tz to the time zone given by to_tz and returns the resulting value. Time zones may be specified as described in Section 5.10.8, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”. This function returns NULL if the arguments are invalid.

If the value falls out of the supported range of the TIMESTAMP type when converted fom from_tz to UTC, no conversion occurs. The TIMESTAMP range is described in Section 11.1.2, “Overview of Date and Time Types”.

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET');
        -> '2004-01-01 13:00:00'

mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','+00:00','+10:00');
        -> '2004-01-01 22:00:00'
```

Comment: note: for the symbolic timezones to work (GMT, PST), you must set up the time zone-related tables in the mysql  database (zoneinfo).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method:

```
$format = Y-m-d; //you can use any format if you want
$date = $row['date']; // from mysql_fetch_array
$date2 = date($format, strtotime("$date + 4 week"));
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use (day/month/year)[Brazilian date format] as below, it doesn't work:

> $todays_date = date("**d/m**/Y H:i:s");
>
> echo "Server date/hour ". $todays_date;
>
> echo "Server date/hour + 2 hours ".date("**d/m**/Y H:i:s",
> strtotime("$todays_date + 2 hours"));

**Result:**

> **Server date/hour**                    **10/04**/2012 07:44:36
>
> **Server date/hour** + 2 hours     **04/10**/2012 09:44:36

---

You need to you (month/day/year) and it works perfect:

> $todays_date = date("**m/d**/Y H:i:s"); echo "Server date/hour ".
>
> $todays_date."
> "; echo ""Server date/hour + 2 hours ".date("**m/d**/Y H:i:s", strtotime("$todays_date + 2 hours"));

**Result:**

> **Server date/hour**                        **04/10**/2012 07:44:36
>
> **Server date/hour** + 2 hours     **04/10**/2012 09:44:36

Answer (score 0):

Working 100%

```
<?php

$datee= date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$last_update+ 10 hours"));
$timee= date("H:i:s", strtotime("$last_update+ 10 hours"));
?>

Last update was on: <?php  echo $datee; ?>  at  <?php  echo $timee; ?>
```

$last_update is a value contents timestamp from mysql

The result will be like this "Last update was on: 2015-02-05 at 05:01:43"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function data_time($DT, $pm, $val, $time_type){
    $time = date("H:i:s");
    $date = date("d.m.Y");

    if($DT=='d'){
        switch($pm){
            case '+': $newData = date("d.m.Y ", strtotime("$date + $val $time_type"));
            break;
            case '-': $newData = date("d.m.Y ", strtotime("$date - $val $time_type"));
            break;
        }
        return $newData;
    }
    if($DT=='t'){
        switch($pm){
            case '+': $newTime = date("H:i:s ", strtotime("$time + $val $time_type"));
            break;
            case '-': $newTime = date("H:i:s ", strtotime("$time - $val $time_type"));
            break;
        }
        return $newTime;
    }
}

$newData = data_time('t','+',5,'year')
//or

$DataTime = 'd'; // 't' or 'd'
$PlusMinus ='+'; // '+' or '-'
$val = 1;        // 0-9
$DMT ='month';   // 'day', 'month' or 'year'

$newData = data_time($DataTime, $PlusMinus, $val, $DMT);
echo $newData;

?>
```

Comment: downvoting: this is badly formatted, much more complicated than other answers without any explanation.

Comment: you find it difficult? enter a 4 value? $newData = data_time(t, '+', 5, day);

Comment: you can change a case to variables or boolean values. This solution includes a lot of features, "sec, min, hours, days, months, years"  Please show your solution, this helpful for me. And sorry for my english Guys, I'm learning. I just showed what i wrote while studying at home, and not copied and pasted.Maybe its help on someone.

Comment: Sorry! I thought, you talk about my code. before, I did not add my scripts to forum. its a first. Tnx, I will try.  A few words about my code please. its a badly wrong ? or, for a learner it's normal ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET field = DATE_ADD(field, INTERVAL 4 HOURS);
```

Hence it is useful in php for adding fucntion to column